# How to prevent re-assigning value to destructured prop from component props?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

```
import React from 'react';

interface ComponentProps {
  readonly name: string;
}

const FnComponent = ({ name }: Readonly<ComponentProps>) => {
  // TS will prevent re-assign a value to props.name at compiler time.
  // props.name = '123'
  // how to prevent the below re-assigning?
  name = '123';
  return <div>{name}</div>
}
```

Re-assign a value to destructured prop is an anti-pattern?

If so, I prefer using TS type system to prevent re-assigning value to the destructured prop at code compiler time. But if there is an eslint rule that can do this, it's also ok.

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wG4Aoc4AOxiSk3STgGFdJqlaAFHMAZzgBvcnDhEUAEwjUANgE841FCCQAuOPxhQaAcwoBfSmhla4AMWptwMrvAC8cABRClK5gY3IpMhQB5rDjteCAEAPgBKOHsw4VE4AHoEuAAVAGU4AHdgWVk4MCIANztxJABaFH5+YF1qOBQ4QpRZAFdmGAh8vn4AOmVVeKSu0N7+5kd8AEYAJgBmfEHkgAsITLgOrqRi2jgAIyRZVdKKqprqPQB+eLHoghn5ijEiGBaoOr9JYEKwoTGDPwSn2+5CMQA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript can't make the destructured prop read-only because parameters are read/write and `name` is no longer part of the `props` object, you've extracted it from it.

You can make it a constant if you destructure within the function body instead:

```typescript
const FnComponent = (props: Readonly<ComponentProps>) => {
     const { name } = props;
     name = "123"; // Error as desired
     return <div>{name}</div>;
};
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wG4Aoc4AOxiSk3STgGFdJqlaAFHMAZzgBvcnDhEUAEwjUANgE841FCCQAuOPxhQaAcwoBfSmhla4AMWptwMrvAC8cABRg+-DcikyFAHmsc7XggBAD4ASjh7EOFRMTETajMhJRVmA0i4V2D+CjixZVUMgCIARgAmAGYi0jgAelq4AFEoHCg4FEFJJH5gIklYuKIYAFcoajgfSWAANxChAqQDH1qp2cMKIA)

> But if there is an eslint rule that can do this, it's also ok.

If you head over to the [ESLint web site](https://eslint.org/), click [Docs](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/), then [Rules](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/), and search for "assign," you'll find [`no-param-reassign`](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/no-param-reassign).